# Как реализовано .upsertMany() в Prisma ORM?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, orm, prisma

В Prisma ORM есть реализация команды [обновить или создать запись `upsert()`](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-client/crud#update-or-create-records), а также группа
[bulk-запросов](https://www.prisma.io/docs/guides/performance-and-optimization/query-optimization-performance#using-bulk-queries),
но среди них нет такого как `.upsertMany()`, то есть массовое "создание или обновление существующих записей".

Как лучше реализовать такой метод, используя [Prisma ORM](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-client/crud)?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64428420/4496422

Comment: какие ещё orm вы использовали? как вам prisma, в сравнении с ними?

Comment: @nörbörnën Раньше я использовал Sequelize, но Prisma, конечно, намного удобнее в плане описания схем и миграций (в Sequelize миграции приходилось писать вручную). Планирую полностью переходить на Prisma.

Comment: ассоциация: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71408235/how-is-upsertmany-implemented-in-prisma-orm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

На данный момент Prisma не имеет стандартной реализации `.upsertMany()`,
(хотя создан [запрос на реализацию](https://github.com/prisma/prisma/issues/4134) метода `.upsertMany()`).

На данный момент лучшим подходом будет вызов массива запросов `.upsert()` обёрнутых в `$transaction()`.

Пример:

```js
const collection = await prisma.$transaction(
  userData.map(cur =>
    prisma.cur.upsert({
      where: { id: cur.id },
      update: {},
      create: { id: cur.id },
    })
  )
)
```

Здесь есть информация о [API `$transaction()`](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-client/transactions#the-transaction-api) , которая также может быть полезной.